# Is it correct to reset sequence value in this case?

Tags: java, database

I have a service which runs every 30mins, reads a XML, deletes all contents of a table (if they differ from the current values on the table) and repopulate it with the new values read from the XML.

Should I be reseting the sequence every time this data table is emptied as well? If so, is there a way I can do this that is not database specific?

Thanks.

Comment: Does the data contain any primary keys that are used as foreign keys by tables that you're not modifying with this process?  You need to be 100% sure no other table or system is tracking the existing sequence numbers and using them, so that you don't break those systems, etc.

Comment: Resetting database sequences should not be performed by application code. Such tasks should be done by a RDBMS. Why do you need to reset them anyway?

Comment: No, there no fks. 100% sure.

Comment: @JamesB because my ids values are getting out of hand. I have about 25 entries on the table and they start with 300xxx

Comment: But why is that a problem? Does it affect your application?

Comment: @JamesB it doesn't. But cant it be a problem if we think about it in a long future? I know a Long maximum value huge, but it could be reached within a lot of years.

Comment: If you do want to do this, then the correct thing to do is probably to *not use a sequence*, not to reset the sequence.

Comment: Some RDBMSs handle this for you though. With Oracle you can define min and max values for a sequence and when max is reached, it restarts automatically at min.

Comment: Just made a quick math, and I would need 21350398233460 years to reach the max value on my current ratio... I guess it is definitely not a problem. Anyway, lets reformulate the question then. Is there a more elegant way to deal with the big id values just for aesthetics?

Comment: It seems that you don't need to use sequence in this case like @immibis said

Comment: What should I use instead as the @IdGenerator strategy then?